# PHP Pass Variables to register_shutdown_function - Fatal Error Handler

Tags: php, error-handling

I know this is not proper error handling, but it is necessary to solve my problem.  I am running a script that parses data in a loop over many hours, so I create a logs of what is happening in the script at various moments to ensure everything is being handled correctly.  All my logs are saved in a different folder than the .php file.  I was recording and logging tons of information.  But, all the connecting to the log file was tremendously slowing down my program.  Instead i have a global $write variable and I just append it.  In order to speed up my program I just want to append my log file with $write, once at the end of each loop.  The problem is that I set a max_execution_time for my program and if it dies before the loop is done, all my logs for that loop are lost.  As part of my register_shutdown_function() I want to log $write.

Here's what I have:

```
register_shutdown_function( "fatal_handler");
function fatal_handler() {

  global $file, $write;
  $errfile = "unknown file";
  $errstr  = "shutdown";
  $errno   = E_CORE_ERROR;
  $errline = 0;

  $error = error_get_last();

  if( $error !== NULL) {
    $errno   = $error["type"];
    $errfile = $error["file"];
    $errline = $error["line"];
    $errstr  = $error["message"];

    file_put_contents($file, "\n\nFATAL ERROR\n\n", FILE_APPEND);
    file_put_contents($file, $write, FILE_APPEND);
  }
}
```

The problem is that I get this error message:
Warning:
file_put_contents(../../resultLogs/log.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\www\php\data_utils\program.php on line 64

Mind you $file works fine in the rest of the program... Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [**docs**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) :

> Working directory of the script can change inside the shutdown
>   function under some web servers, e.g. Apache.

So be sure to use an absolute path when doing this, i.e

```
file_put_contents('<absolute-path-to>/resultLogs/log.txt', $write, FILE_APPEND);
```

As you wrote "*All my logs are saved in a different folder than the .php file*", and I guess that your problem is, that you are having the `$file` constant relative to that `.php` file but the directory changes upon error..